# Cannot access WordPress login pages

Tags: wp-admin, login

I cannot access either wp-admin, or wp-login.php on a wordpress site.  I'm **not** getting a 404, or a redirect, it simply says cannot connect in firefox.

I have tried everything relevant on this [guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble) and also this [guide](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/common-wordpress-errors-with-solutions/), but nothing helps, still the same error.

Comment: Says `The connection to www.caboolturegateway.com.au was interrupted.` - Have you contacted your hosting provider?

Comment: No, as the rest of the site site is working fine, its just the wordpress logins that aren't working so I presumed it was a wordpress issue.

Comment: That could be due to a number of things: host's web server configuration, your setup, your .htaccess file configuration, etc.  Is that site a WP site?  Seems like you installed WP into an existing site.  If you did, then there is a conflict that prevents WP from running.  Did you actually go through the WP installation where you create your admin user and setup the db?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was an IP block on just the admin errors of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the control panel for wordpress just go to your browser and type in this http://localhost/foldername/wp-login.php?
There you are free to go make sure you don't leave out a question mark at the end.
  Respond if it works for you.